# iOS: How to open my app files in safari

Tags: ios, uiapplication

- I need to open my files from documents folder in `safari`
- I tried using `[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:` type.
- I would like to open my local file from my app

**Eg:** `file:///var/mobile/Applications/F60EDF96-A87C-4282-B239-E24E84AA331F/Documents/BDMAR-03U.pdf`

- Is it possible to open above url in `safari`

**Code Tried:**

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:my_above_url]];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it! Other app can't get access to files in sandbox!